# Using wamp server error in connecting between pages

Tags: php, hyperlink, wamp

I have installed wamp to my E drive. When I use projects in www directory the localhost disappears from addressbar and when I write localhost it works but I can't send data between pages (especially in dreamweaver(I defined site and testing server)) and I can't link pages(the links is not working).
what shoud I do?
I tried solutions in other answers like uninstall services but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you're linking like this `page2.htm` and not `/page2.htm` because the first is relative (so it will link to page2 in the same folder) whereas the other will link to page2 in the root folder)

Comment: Do you mean you create subfolder under the `\wamp\www` folder or have you put your site in the `www` folder.

Comment: How are u creating these links?

Comment: Read this for the solution:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Read this for the solution:- stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/… –  RiggsFolly yesterday  ---I tried it, It wasn't useful.

Comment: I create links in normal ways. Like html links or submit and others

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me before, after installing newer version of wamp server, i suggest you install lower version of wamp server hope this help.